# Is there a way to take a photo with OpenCV, not using a camera

Tags: python, opencv

I am using OpenCV to capture an image from a camera. The camera I'm using a camera that captures static images in 4k, but video in 1080p. Is there a way to take a photo in OpenCV without using videoCapture()?

```
def takephoto(camNumber):

#This creates two variables, the first one 'date' that records the exact date and time when   the photo was taken and the second one 'imagePath' that records where the image should be stored to
date = datetime.now().strftime("%Y_%m_%d-%I-%M-%S_%p")
imagePath = r'path'

#creates a variable called camera and makes it record what the webcam is displaying
camera = cv2.VideoCapture(camNumber)

#Creates a new variable called image and tells it to record what camera has stored in it at that moment
return_value, image = camera.read()

del(camera)
        
image = NULL
print("Photo Done")
return image, date
```

Comment: No, there isn't any other way to capture webcam image but can you explain what is the issue with using `cv2.VideoCapture()` module?

Comment: You didn't mention your camera make & model or your Operating System. Please click [edit] and add in these details.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think so.
other than opencv, you can capture the image using pygame library.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-capture-a-image-from-webcam-in-python/

```
import pygame
import pygame.camera
  
# initializing  the camera
pygame.camera.init()
  
# make the list of all available cameras
camlist = pygame.camera.list_cameras()
  
# if camera is detected or not
if camlist:
  
    # initializing the cam variable with default camera
    cam = pygame.camera.Camera(camlist[0], (640, 480))
  
    # opening the camera
    cam.start()
  
    # capturing the single image
    image = cam.get_image()
  
    # saving the image
    pygame.image.save(image, "filename.jpg")
```

Comment: What do the (640, 480) parameters mean in ```cam = pygame.camera.Camera(camlist[0], (640, 480))```

Comment: its size of the window 640 by 480